# storyboard jumps to an empty space

Tags: xcode, storyboard

When I load my storyboard (click on the navigation pane) it jumps to an empty space and I need to scroll to reach the relevant area I want to be in. Really annoying
In the past, it returned to the last place I was in the storyboard before leaving the screen

Any ideas how to fix it? (configuration?)

Answer (score 0):

For future reference

apparently I had a windows with the storyboard open (after double clicking on it) - this was the cause for the problem
(I guess when there is a window with a file opened - when you single click it to open in the main window it goes to the same point